# How to import external CSV by URL into MySQL database?

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I am building a PHP page, but I don't know how to import external CSV by URL  into the database.

For my code, `$url=http://www.example.com/123.csv;`, how can I import the file content of 123.csv into the database, thanks.

Comment: Either make it into an array or download it locally for LOAD DATA INFILE

Comment: `load data infile '$url'`

Comment: But I try this before


`$surl = 'http://www.example.com/123.csv';
$scontent = trim(file_get_contents($surl));
$scontent = substr($scontent, 0, -1);
$scontent = iconv('UTF-16LE', 'UTF-8', $scontent);
$slines = explode("\n", $scontent);
$slines = array_slice($slines, 2);

foreach($slines as $sline){
$sdata = str_getcsv($sline, "\t");
$scmd = mysql_query("INSERT INTO index(code,ename,cname) VALUES ('$sdata[2]','$sdata[3]','$sdata[4]')") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_query($scmd);
}`

Comment: But it prompts me the message "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near"

How can I fix this bug?thanks.